# Disable syntax-highlighting for code style in Gogs

Tags: markdown, gogs

How can I disable syntax highlighting in [Gogs](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/) for an (intented) code block in the `README.md`? The problem is that the commands described in the readme are self-defined but contain keywords of other programming languages, therefore the code is highlighted in an odd manner.

According to [Markdown Syntax cheatsheet](https://sourceforge.net/p/gogs/wiki/markdown_syntax/#md_ex_code) I tried:

`:::python
my_function(param1, param2)`

but it does not make any change. I think it is ignored by Gogs. As well the notation

`~~~python
my_function(param1, param2)
~~~`

did not make any change. Can't syntax highlighting be disabled in Gogs Markdown?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to indicate the block is just a simple text by marking it as "text", as shown, below:

````
```text
this is a simple text
```
````

(three backticks work the same as three tildes)

Gogs uses [blackfriday](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday) for rendering the markdown, although it's not documented the "text" option there, their documentation might be the best place to check the implemented features of the markdown on Gogs.